# How is it decided which accounts icons to show next to your name?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I notice in the picture below that different account icons are shown with our gravitar icons and total rep.

How is this set decided?  Is there any importance to them?  Why are they there?

[Image of site icons http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/9602/associatedaccounts.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2868/apocalyptic-defense)

Comment: The tag for Area 51 is [area51], not [area-51]

Comment: @neil The official name is Area[space]51.  So, I think we may be switching to the hyphenated tag.

Comment: To make your point clear, freehand circles would be appreciated. But I guess hovering with the mouse over the icons will clear this case.

Comment: Number of posts for [area51] - 82. Number of posts for [area-51] - zero. As someone that wants to exclude these posts I don't care which one you use so long as you all use the same one.

Comment: Jeff created the tag, so you can take it up with him. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/51998/revisions

Answer (score 5):

The icon is shown if the user has more than 200 rep in one of the associated accounts. Quoting the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> If you have **more than 200 reputation on associated accounts** on other sites, we'll show that in your user information when you follow or commit to a proposal. This is an easy way for others to see at-a-glance your achievements across the entire network!

Comment: Odd. I have more than 200 on two sites besides SO. One (Food and Cooking) is shown and the other (Programmers) isn't.

Comment: @configurator: It may take a day or two for the icon to appear, from when you reached 200.